# C# switch case doesn't appear

Tags: c#

So, i'm kinda new to the whole C# language and someone asked us to convert their simple if else to a switch. This is all i know. is it correct? if not can you tell me where the problem is? or is there something missing? the only problem here is that the switch case's output doesn't appear.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
        string studname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Age: ");
        string age = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Year Level: ");
        int level = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Course: ");
        string course = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Score 1: ");
        int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Score 2: ");
        int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Score 3: ");
        int num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int total = num1 + num2 + num3;
        int ave = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;
        int rate = ave;




        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Student Name: " + studname);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Student Age: " + age);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Student Year Level: " + level);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Student Course: " + course);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Score 1: " + num1);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Score 2: " + num2);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Score 3: " + num3);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Total_Score= " + total);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Total_Average= " + ave);


        switch (rate)
        {
            case 1:
                if (rate < 100 && rate > 90)

                Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
                Console.WriteLine("");
               break;


            case 2:
                if (rate < 89 && rate > 85)

                    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;

            case 3:
                if (rate < 84 && rate > 80)

                    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;

            case 4:
                if (rate < 79 && rate > 75)

                    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;

            case 5:
                if (rate < 75)

                    Console.Write("Rate = 5.00");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Failed");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                break;


        }





        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: The words 'refactor' and DRY spring to mind...

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what a `switch`-block does. It's used if the value that you're testing only takes one of a few set values.

Try getting rid of the `switch`-block entirely and re-write this to use a series of `if`/`else`-blocks instead. Also note, you need to handle edge cases like `rate = 90`; you need to check `rate >= 90` to capture this case as well:

```
if (rate < 100 && rate >= 90)
{
    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else if (rate < 89 && rate >= 85)
{
    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else ...
```

Or if you really want to do the same thing in each of these cases unless `rate < 75`, you can just simplify this to:

```
if (rate >= 75)
{
    Console.Write("Rate = 1.00");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Passed");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
else
{
     Console.Write("Rate = 5.00");
     Console.WriteLine("");
     Console.Write("Hi! " + studname + "you Failed");
     Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Or even just something like this:

```
Console.Write("Rate = {0}", (rate >= 75) ? "1.00" : "5.00");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.Write("Hi! {0} you {1}", studname, (rate >= 75) ? "Passed" : "Failed");
Console.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: it sounds like the OP started with an if statement and wanted to write it as a switch-case...not that that makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your case values are not correct, the switch statement is switching on the case value, so in this case, case 1 will only be called if rate == 1, and so forth, so you need to modified those values in order to have it output.